# RMI: How to place server-side & client-side classes to network-accessible location?

Tags: java, rmi

I am new to RMI

I understand what RMI mean, I already tried this [example](http://www.java2all.com/1/5/22/114/Technology/RMI/RMI-Program/RMI-example) and it works well. when I tried this example, I tried it in two different ways.

- **One** folder
  All the related files (Interfaces, Client classes and Server classes) in one folder.
- **Two** different folders (in the same PC) - *to see what will happen when they are separated*
  One folder contains: Interfaces and Client classes.
  The other folder contains: Interfaces and Server classes.

Both ways work well.

I was planning to try this example in two different PCs. But someone advised me that this example is very out of date, and must read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html).

I read it and I almost understand everything up to the point I stuck in.
I reached to this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/compiling.html)

> After you build either server-side or client-side classes with the
>   javac compiler, if any of those classes will need to be dynamically
>   downloaded by other Java virtual machines, you must ensure that their
>   class files are placed in a network-accessible location

I think the tutorial assumes the reader have some knowledge about web-server issues. (Which I haven't)
I completed reading to the end of the page, but I didn't understand where exactly I have to place my classes files.

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.
I have two guesses about the **network-accessible location** which are: (Maybe they are silly guesses - sorry)

1- The name of my PC is "S", so the **network-accessible location** might be "C:\Users\S" or somewhere inside it.

2- I installed [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi) "httpd-2.0.64-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8o.msi", and I think the **network-accessible location** is somewhere relevant to this Apache server.

So my problem is to locate the **network-accessible location**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice it means you must put them in an HTTP server so they can be retrieved via an HTTP: URL. It's best to put the JAR file there, not just a directory system of .class files.

You can use network shares and file: URLs but it really doesn't work well. The URL(s) in the codebase entry has/have to be the same for both server and client, so even if the files are local on the server filesystem you still need to have the same shared drive that the client sees. I don't recommend that applications use shared drives for *anything,* including this.